# Are there formal systems that allow you to make human-like higher-order statements?

Tags: prolog, logic, artificial-intelligence, logic-programming

For humans, it's very natural to make higher-order statements. For example, you could state the following (with pseudo-`Prolog` syntax):

---

Socrates is smart:

```
smart(socrates).
```

John is a man:

```
man(john).
```

Socrates believes all men are mortal:

```
believes(socrates, (mortal(X) :- man(X))).
```

If someone is smart and believes something, it must be true:

```
Y :- smart(X), believes(X, Y).
```

---

I checked out a couple of "higher-order" extensions to `Prolog`, but neither can accept the kinds of statements like the last two examples.

Are there formal systems that allow you to make human-like higher-order statements, such as these?

Comment: Pointers: [Epistemic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/) at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, [this subentry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ai/#knowledge) of [Logic and AI](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ai/) and the book [Reasoning about Knowledge](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/reasoning-about-knowledge) which I really should read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), and is theorized with [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics).  Here are [some libraries in python](https://github.com/topics/modal-logic).